# onActivityResult not working on API 23

Tags: java, android, sdk

The onActivityResult method returns blank data or is not called when picking an image from Gallery. My implementation works fine on API 16, 17...22 but I am having problems with API 23. I read this article: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Accessing-the-Camera-and-Stored-Media , about permissions.

My client has tested the app on 3 phones running Android 6 
and they all have the same behavior when picking a image. You can see an activity screenshot, there are 3 ImageButtons (a big one, and 2 small ones), when user clicks on an ImageButton the gallery is triggered for picking an image, when user picks an image the ImageButton just gets grey instead of showing the picked image.

```
////onclick method///photo2 is a imagebutton////SELECT_PICTURE2 is the code

photo2_evento.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Escoge
             una imagen"), SELECT_PICTURE2);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE2);

        }
    });

///onactivityResult
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent
 data) {
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
           if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

              try{

               Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();        


             if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE1) {

                   photo1_path = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                photo1_evento.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(photo1_path, 400, 400));


                }else if(requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE2){

                    photo2_path = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                    photo2_evento.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(photo2_path, 100, 100));


                }else if(requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE3){

                    photo3_path = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);             

                    photo3_evento.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(photo3_path, 100, 100)); 



                }

              }catch(Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {

                  e.printStackTrace();
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"memory error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }


                }




}

////decodeSampledBitmapFromResource is just a method provided by Google     Android for sizing images.

////this method is for getting the URI path, I got this code from stackoverflow
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {


       String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
       Cursor cursor = null;
       try {
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
               // Will return "image:x*"
               String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(contentUri);
               // Split at colon, use second item in the array
               String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];
               // where id is equal to
               String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

               cursor = Publicar_Eventos.this.getContentResolver().query(
                       MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                       projection, sel, new String[] { id }, null);
           } else {
               cursor = Publicar_Eventos.this.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                       projection, null, null, null);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {

           e.printStackTrace();
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"error de memoria", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

       String path = null;
       try {
           int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           path = cursor.getString(column_index).toString();
           cursor.close();
       } catch (NullPointerException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return path;
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Potential issues: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` or `noHistory="true"` in the manifest

Comment: Is the deubugger even hitting the `onActivityResult`?

Comment: Hi, I haven't added those properties to my Android manifest, but I think it's a permission issue so far as I have read, Marshmallow requires some runtime permissions.

Comment: I haven't tested the app on the emulator, so I don't know whether onActivityresult is hit , Eclipse's emulator is too slow for performing this action (picking image from gallery)

Comment: Oh yes! You would need something like `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);` and so on before you can actually "read" the activity result.

Comment: [[Android permission docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)] speaks about this in great detail.